# Storing model names on database and retrieving the data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am making a web site which requires to have locations on different category. I want to store model name in the database and fetch using the value retrieved from the database.

I have a hotel model

```
-id
-name
```

And I have  restaurant model

```
-id 
-name
```

And i have location model

```
-id
-name
-latitude
-longitude
-modal_name
```

I want to store `App\Hotel` in `modal_name` column and want to fetch data from the same model.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Check the polymorphic [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use polymorphic relation.

You should add to your locations table 2 fields ( 1 for the model name and 1 for the id key on that model ) and the naming convention is usually ****able_type and ***able_id 
for instance: `locationable_type` and `locationable_id`.

than on your location model add the following relation

```
class Location extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning locationable models.
     */
    public function locationable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

than on your hotel model add this relation

```
class Hotel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the hotel location.
     */
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Location', 'locationable');
    }
}
```

same thing for your restaurant model

```
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the restaurant location.
     */
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Location', 'locationable');
    }
}
```

than to use it you simply can use:

```
$hotel = App\Hotel::find(1);

dd($hotel->location);
```

for more information you can checkout [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Good luck :)